# Vue prop type validation object schema

Tags: validation, vue.js, vuejs2

In React you can define that a prop is an object and then also define the types of that object's properties, i.e the shape.  In Vue it seems the only way you can check to see if an object is of a certain shape is by using the validator function.  Is that currently the recommended strategy?  I'm sure there other libraries I can use to handle that validation but it seems like something Vue should be able to handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely use [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/). What you are expecting is called "type annotation", you will get a quick overview on [TypeScript Quick start tutorial](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/tutorial.html).

Vue.js has TypeScript support out of the box. See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html

Comment: Word, I was afraid that was the answer.  I'm aware of TypeScript but it seems like overkill for a small two person project, but component prop validation seemed worthwhile to us. Perhaps now's a good time to bite the bullet. Thanks

Comment: It's always a good time to improve your code and your skills! Go TypeScript, you won't regret that :)

Comment: I'd use Vue PropTypes if you just need that, no need of TypeScript.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with a TypeScript only solution is that it only checks types at *compile-time* and is limited to type checking.  This won't help you at *run-time* if you're passing in dynamic objects or need additional data constraints.

I recently found a library that for run-time validation but it wasn't well suited for use with Vue 2.x or the Babel compiler as it used JavaScript reserved words as function names.  So I forked the project, refactored the code to support both TypeScript and JavaScript and specifically added an `asSuccess()` function to support validation of VueJS object properties.

So if you had a TypeScript interface like ...

```js
interface Pet {
  name: string;
  species: string;
  age?: number;
  isCute?: boolean;
}
```

You could validate a Pet property using either JavaScript or TypeScript code as ...

```js
import { tObject, tString, tNumber, tBoolean, optional } from 'runtime-validator'

// VueJs component
export default {
  name: 'MyPet',
  props: {
    pet: {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
      validator: tObject({
        name: tString(),
        species: tString(),
        age: optional(tNumber()),
        isCute: optional(tBoolean())
      }).asSuccess
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

`tObject()` will accept objects having additional fields to those defined. If you need to disallow additional fields, use `tObjectStrict()`.

You can also add value constraints ...

```js
export default {
  name: 'MyPet',
  props: {
    pet: {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
      validator: tObject({
        name: tString(),
        species: oneOf("cat", "dog", "bird"),
        age: optional(range(0, 150)),
        isCute: optional(tBoolean())
      }).asSuccess
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

It has much broader application than properties as it can also be used for data validation in unit testing, vuex actions and mutations, server-side payloads and more.

Full documentation is here ...

- https://github.com/tohagan/runtime-validation/

Comment: You can also use this library to create Typescript type guards. Not just basic ones but arbitrary complex nested types with things like value range checking or regex patterns etc checking then apply that to all array elements or other nested types (so way more than Typescript alone can do).

Comment: Another alternative library if you're using TypeScript is 'zod'
- https://github.com/colinhacks/zod

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to piggyback off of @Clorichel's answer because TypeScript is doing wonders for me. It's a late answer, but I've been needing the same thing as you: object schema validation, not just simply "[is this prop a string or number?](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Prop-Validation)". TypeScript offers the usage of an [interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html), which contractually bounds the shape of an object to that type (interface). So if I have

```
interface GreetingSchema {
  message: string;
}
```

doing `let myGreeting = <GreetingSchema>{ message: 1234 }` is going to throw the error

```
Type '{ message: number; }' cannot be converted to type 'GreetingSchema'.
  Types of property 'message' are incompatible.
    Type 'number' is not comparable to type 'string'.
```

To extend this a little further by integrating it with Vue, you can leverage interfaces during compile time to perform object schema validation on component props that are passed down from parents to children. For example, a child `Greeting` component (Greeting.vue) can be coupled with the object schema for the props that will be passed to it (I'm using a nested schema to spice things up):

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{message}}{{
      speaker
        ? ` from ${speaker.firstName}${
            speaker.lastName ? ` ${speaker.lastName}` : ''
          }
        : ''
    }}
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
export default {
  name: 'greeting',
  props: ['message', 'speaker'],
}

interface SpeakerSchema { // this will be a nested schema
  firstName: string;
  lastName?: string; // last name of speaker is optional
}

export interface GreetingSchema {
  message: string;
  speaker?: SpeakerSchema; // speaker is optional
}
</script>
```

You may then import the `Greeting` component along with its corresponding `GreetingSchema` into the parent to ensure that whenever the parent passes its `greetingData` down to a child `Greeting` with `v-bind`, `greetingData` is going to be bound by the shape defined in `GreetingSchema`

```
<template>
  <div>
    This greeting is being displayed from the parent:
    <greeting v-bind="greetingData" /> 
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Greeting, {GreetingSchema} from './Greeting' // path to Greeting.vue

export default {
  name: 'parent',
  components: {Greeting},
  data () {
    return {
      greetingData: <GreetingSchema>{
        message: 'hi there',
        speaker: {
          firstName: 'myFirstName',
          lastName: 1234 // error because it's not a string
        },
      }
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

What's awesome is that the errors can be shown directly in your text editor with the right extensions, even in `.vue` files. I'm using [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), which has TypeScript support out of the box, with the [vetur extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=octref.vetur). What's even awesomer is that [TypeScript's home page features a presentation in which TypeScript is used with Vue's single file components](https://www.typescriptlang.org/index.html)!